# How do I assert on the body of the post request where the body is returned as an array

Tags: post, request, response, cypress

I am trying to assert the post request body. 
I am able to do this normally, but in this case, the body is returned as an array

I have the following:

```
      .then((response) => {
       expect(response.body).to.have.property('EntityDirectory')
       })
```

The following array is returned:

```
    0: {cardID: "1" , taxref: "00000000", companyID: "1" )
    1: {cardID: "1" , taxref: "00000000", companyID: "1" )
    0: {cardID: "1" , taxref: "00000000", companyID: "1" )
```

How do I put in the expected array in my response body?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [deep.equal](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#BDD-Assertions).

```
  .then((response) => {
     expect(response.body).to.deep.equal(expectedArray)
   })
```